# Randomize a color with a condition

Tags: java, random

I want to randomize a color, but with the somewhat obscure condition: Color mustn't be a shade of grey (hence, close to black/white).

What would be a neat way to do that?

**My thought:**
picking a basic palette of colors and then pick one randomly, and "playing" with it's RGB parameters.

Comment: if you generate randomly your R, G and B values, you could check that they are not too near each other :-)

Comment: Look into HSV colors, it will make the problem a lot easier to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors can be represented in ways other than a mix of red, green and blue. One model that will work better for this is a method called [HSV](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (there is a similar model called HSL) meaning Hue, Saturation and Value. The Hue is the frequency of the color (rotation position on a color wheel) while saturation and value control how vibrant and how dark/light the color appears. Decide on a range for S and V then pick a random Hue and you should be good.

Comment: This is the best way to do it.  Note that you can use the `getHSBColor` method of the `Color` class to make your `Color`, once you've got H, S and V.  (No idea why they didn't call it `getHSVColor`).

Comment: Incidentally, HSL is not the same thing as HSV.  It doesn't matter though, in terms of your answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I linked to Wikipedia and fixed my mistake, thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

Generate value1 in range 0 to 255.

Generate value2 in range 0 to (value1 - 100) and (value1 + 100) to 255

Generate value3 in range 0 to min(value1,value2) - 100 and min(value1,value2) + 100 to 255.

Randomly assign value1,value2 and value3 to R G and B.

Comment: I dislike this idea.  It cuts out too many colours that aren't grey.  You'll never get anything close to one of the primary or secondary colours this way.  There'll never be any nice saturated red, or yellow, or green.  There'll basically be six different groups of colours, each close to a "tertiary" colour (orange, yellowish green etc).

Answer (score 1):

Generate random values for red (r), green (g) and blue (b).  Then calculate

```
(r - g) * (r - g) + (r - b) * (r - b) + (g - b) * (g - b)
```

This quantity will give you a measure for how far away from grey the colour is.  Zero would mean it's grey or black or white.  A large number would mean it's saturated.

So, if this number turns out to be less than a certain threshold (maybe 5000 or so) then regenerate the numbers.  You may have to play around a little to find the best threshold value for your needs.

The simplest way to structure this is probably with a do-while loop.